# Forwarding mail to local mailserver

Tags: email, sendmail

I have three servers running sendmail as an MTA: mail.example.com, alpha.example.com and bravo.example.com. The first one, mail.example.com holds the email for users and provides IMAP service, for recipients other than example.com it sends to an ISP MTA.

I want scripts on alpha and bravo to be able to send email alerts to joe@example.com that joe can pick up in his regular email using IMAP from mail.example.com.

How do I configure sendmail on alpha and bravo to send mail to joe@example.com to mail.example.com rather than to joe's account on the sending machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

alpha and bravo will only consider mail for joe@example.com to be local if they have example.com defined in /etc/mail/local-host-names.

Each host should have it's hostname listed, not the domain name. mail.example.com should have both it's hostname and the domain name listed.

Mail should then route correctly, so long as your MX records are also correct.

Comment: That helped. I should have mentioned that mail.example.com replaced alpha.example.com as the LAN email server and so the local-host-names file on alpha did indeed contain example.com as well as alpha.example.com